# What effect does Nvidia hash rate limiting have on power efficiency?

Tags: gpu, nvidia, power-consumption

NVidia is rate limiting some cards to 50% of possible hashrate. What effect does this have on power efficiency?

I can imagine it reducing power efficiency (same power, but lower hashrate). On the other hand I could imagine it increase power efficiency (by cutting voltage when it detects hashing, halving performance but doubling power efficiency). I haven't bought a card yet so I cannot test.

Comment: My card is getting speed: `speed:   54.12 MH/s   power:  121.06 W   efficiency:  447.04 kH/J` in nicehash. I think this means it is not ratelimited. Does anyone have a rate limited card to compare?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Low Hash Rate (LHR) card to compare to. However NiceHash now posts profitability stats for LHR cards: https://www.nicehash.com/profitability-calculator/nvidia-rtx-3060-ti/nvidia-rtx-3060-ti-lhr. I understand NiceHash primarily mines Ethereum.

Currently (4th Jan 2022), it reports that the RTX 3060 Ti can still make a profit at 1 USD per KWH, but the RTX 3060 Ti LHR would make a loss.  From this, I deduce that LHR reduces efficiency as well as speed.